# Testing Exogeneity of regressors

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, predictor, instrumental-variables, exogeneity

**Good evening,
I have a problem with solving this exercise:**

[image]

I could calculate the F-Statistics with the weak instrument test on my own. But I don't know how to test for exogeneity with two endogenous variables.
From the lectures I know how to work with one endogenous variable:
[image]

**With the R-Code:**

[image]

**So my question: How can I calculate the test statistic with two
endogenous variables?**

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).